# Editar dos modelos en una vista asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

soy nuevo en este lenguaje y necesito de su ayuda.
Tengo tres tablas Alumno, Tutor, Colegio. A la hora de agregar un nuevo alumno, también agrego un nuevo tutor y selecciono de una lista el colegio. Hasta ahi el insert funciona perfecto. El inconveniente es a la hora de actualizar los datos que no se como solucionarlo, quiero modificar el nombre del tutor y me da error. Agradezco de antemano el que me pueda orientar

Los Modelos

```
public class Alumno
{
    public int AlumnoId { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    public int TutorId { get; set; }
    public int ColegioId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tutor Tutor { get; set; }
    public virtual Colegio Colegio { get; set; }
}

public class Colegio
{
    public int ColegioId { get; set; }
    public string ColegioNombre { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Alumno>Alumno { get; set; }
}

public class Tutor
{
    public int TutorId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Alumno> Alumno { get; set; }
}
```

El ViewModel para usar Alumno y tutor en la misma vista

```
public class DosModelos
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TutorId { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }

}
```

El controlador para Editar el alumno y a la vez el tutor

```
     // GET: Alumno/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Alumno alumno = db.Alumno.Find(id);


        if (alumno == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.ColegioId = new SelectList(db.Colegio, "ColegioId", "ColegioNombre", 
        alumno.ColegioId);

        return View(alumno);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "AlumnoId,Apellido,TutorId,ColegioId")] Alumno 
       alumno)
    {
         Tutor tutorEdit = new Tutor();
         tutorEdit = alumno.Tutor;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(tutorEdit.Nombre).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(alumno).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ColegioId = new SelectList(db.Colegio, "ColegioId", "ColegioNombre", 
         alumno.ColegioId);

        return View(alumno);
    }
```

La Vista

```
  @model ViewModel.Models.Alumno

  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
   }

  <h2>Edit</h2>


 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Alumno</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlumnoId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Apellido, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apellido, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apellido, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tutor.Nombre, "TutorNombre", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Tutor.Nombre)                
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ColegioId, "ColegioId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
    "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ColegioId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" 
       })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ColegioId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" 
       })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  }

  <div>
       @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </div>

   @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

El error es Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
 db.Entry(tutorEdit.Nombre).State = EntityState.Modified;

Desde ya agradez su aporte

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando mal el concepto de ViewModels.

Reemplaza:

```
public class DosModelos
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TutorId { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }

}
```

Por:

```
public class DosModelos
{
    public Alumno Alumno { get; set; }
    public Tutor Tutor { get; set; }
}
```

Luego en tu controlador:

```
// GET: Alumno/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{

    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Alumno alumno = db.Alumno.Find(id);
    // Aqui creas el ViewModel:
    var dosModelos = new DosModelos();
    dosModelos.Alumno = alumno;
    dosModelos.Tutor = new Tutor();  
    if (alumno == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.ColegioId = new SelectList(db.Colegio, "ColegioId", "ColegioNombre", 
    alumno.ColegioId);

    return View(alumno);
}
```

Y asumiendo que los datos los estás enviando correctamente al controlador Post:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "AlumnoId,Apellido,TutorId,ColegioId")] Alumno 
   alumno)
{
     Tutor tutorEdit = new Tutor();
     tutorEdit = alumno.Tutor;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {


        // Aqui te hace falta especificar qué cosas modificar, por ejemplo:
        var existingBlog = new Blog { BlogId = 1, Name = "ADO.NET Blog" };
        using (var context = new BloggingContext()) {
            context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Modified;
            // Modificar a gusto las propiedades
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // OJO con la base de datos, la tabla debe ser la entidad que estás usando, en este caso, me late que utilizas "tutor"
        db.Entry(tutor).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(alumno).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.ColegioId = new SelectList(db.Colegio, "ColegioId", "ColegioNombre", 
     alumno.ColegioId);

    return View(alumno);
}
```

Lecturas recomendadas:

Documentación oficial de Entity Framework:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Workshop maratónico de ASP.net MVC 5 + Entity Framework + jQuery: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY